# Does any setBackground-like method exist for API under 16?

Tags: java, android, api, button, background

I was trying to make my custom button change when clicked arranging a solution like this:

....

```
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    boolean i1 = false;
```

....

```
        View.OnClickListener gestore = new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View view) {

                Resources res = getResources();
                Drawable shape = res. getDrawable(R.drawable.round_shape);
                Drawable shape_clicked = res. getDrawable(R.drawable.round_shape_clicked);


            switch(view.getId()){

              case R.id.button1:

                  i1 = !i1;
                  button1.setBackground(i1 == true ? shape_clicked : shape);  
                break;

              case R.id.button2:

                  i2 = !i2;
                  button2.setBackground(i2 == true ? shape_clicked : shape);  
                break;
```

Unluckily I found out that this method (setBackground) works only from API 16.
How can I manage to do the same thing with lower APIs?
Thanks for any answer and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
int build = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; 
if(build < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
{
    setBackgroundDrawable(i1 == true ? shape_clicked : shape);
}
else
{
    setBackground(i1 == true ? shape_clicked : shape);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:
button.setBackgroundResource(resid) like:

```
int build = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; 
if(build < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
{
       button1.setBackgroundResource(i1 == true ? R.drawable.round_shape : R.drawable.round_shape_clicked);
}
else
{
       button1.setBackground(i1 == true ? shape_clicked : shape);
}
```